# Redux useSelector don't work when called by a publish pub/sub

Tags: reactjs, redux, useselector

I have an issue with my eventBus and data from useSelector
Below my sample

```
const toto = useSelector(state => state.toto);

const test = () => {
   console.log(toto); // always null
}

useEffect(()=>{
    console.log(toto); // always good when toto change whatever in my components
}, [toto]);

useEffect(()=>{
   subscribe('showtoto', test); 
   subscribe('showtoto', () => test()); 
},[])
```

i update toto in some components, the useEffect show always the mutation and the good data for toto.
After in a component i publish the event 'showtoto'.
test is executed but toto is always null.

Anyone have an idea, what's wrong?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why is there a pub/sub mechanism in an app that uses redux? (redux actions are events basically).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add the todo property to dependency array in useEffect

```
useEffect(()=>{
   test()
   subscribe('showtoto', test); 
   subscribe('showtoto', () => test()); 
},[todo])
```

Comment: Thanks it works ! 
But is there another solution ? because in my real code there is 5 data to watch and in this case i have to unsubscribe and subscribe at each update on each data. Lot of cpu no ?

Comment: or you can just prevent subscribing if it's already subscribed?

Comment: if i do that i will come back to the issue, the subscribe will be before the updated data.